# Browser not refreshing

Tags: asp.net

This is my first post, so please be gentle. With regard to the markup and code below (this is all inside a user control), this works fine to begin with. The problem occurs when I try to delete more than one item from the list that the formview renders.

I can delete an item and the page reloads and the item that I deleted is gone. If I then click delete on another item there is no apparent response at all. Putting breakpoints on all of the functions etc in the page behind shows that it does actually go through everything that it should do, but the browser shows no response at all. If I then manually refresh the browser the second item that I have deleted has gone.

I really need to get the browser to refresh every time I click delete and if possible I could do with understanding the problem please. I have tried using ViewStateMode="Disabled/Enabled" in both the formview and the repeater separately and together.

Additional - I have also tried disabling caching.

Thanks in advance.

```
<asp:FormView ID="fvDrugActiveSubstance" runat="server" DefaultMode="ReadOnly" UseSubmitBehavior="false" Width="100%">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <th style="width:80%;">Name</th>
                <th style="width:10%;">Edit</th>
                <th style="width:10%;">Delete</th>
            </tr>
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptrDrugActiveSubstance" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptrDrugActiveSubstance_ItemCommand">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr class="view_table" style="">
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label  Text='<%# Eval("ActiveSubstanceName") %>' ID="lblName" runat="server" />
                            <asp:Label  Text='<%# Eval("DrugSafetyDrugCode") %>' ID="lblCode" runat="server" Visible="false" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img onclick='<%# String.Format("openDrugActiveSubstanceWindow( {1},{0},\"Write\" );return false;",((DrugActiveSubstance)Container.DataItem).DrugSafetyDrugCode.ToString(),((DrugActiveSubstance)Container.DataItem).DrugSafetyDrugActiveSubstanceCode) %>' src="/images/grid_icons/edit.png" style="cursor: pointer;" title="Edit" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("DrugSafetyDrugActiveSubstanceCode") %>' style="cursor: pointer;" CommandName="cmd_delete" ImageUrl="~/images/grid_icons/Delete.gif" ToolTip="Delete" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                    <tr class="view_table_alt">
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label  Text='<%# Eval("ActiveSubstanceName") %>' ID="lblName" runat="server" />
                            <asp:Label  Text='<%# Eval("DrugSafetyDrugCode") %>' ID="lblCode" runat="server" Visible="false" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img onclick='<%# String.Format("openDrugActiveSubstanceWindow( {1},{0},\"Write\" );return false;",((DrugActiveSubstance)Container.DataItem).DrugSafetyDrugCode.ToString(),((DrugActiveSubstance)Container.DataItem).DrugSafetyDrugActiveSubstanceCode) %>' src="/images/grid_icons/edit.png" style="cursor: pointer;" title="Edit" />
                        </td>
                        <td id="tdDelete">
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("DrugSafetyDrugActiveSubstanceCode") %>' style="cursor: pointer;" CommandName="cmd_delete" ImageUrl="~/images/grid_icons/Delete.gif" ToolTip="Delete" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </AlternatingItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>



protected void rptrDrugActiveSubstance_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    drugSafetyService.DeleteDrugActiveSubstance(int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString()));
    Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().Split('?')[0] + "?#drugAS_accordian");
}
```

Comment: Open developer tools on Chrome and check what is the response from the server. Check if you have any change in the HTTP response.

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried that & got 200 and 304 under result for the first click (the successful one) then (Aborted) under result for the second click. I have no idea what that means other than the obvious. I don't understand what aborted or why.

Comment: A 304 means "Not Modified" (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) and it is only used in GET http responses. This means that you are performing a GET, not a POST. Please check what is on the onclick property of btnDelete button after the first click

Comment: This is a large & over-coded web site that I inherited from my predecessor. After a lot of messing about I have found a javascript function which was causing the abort & now everything works fine. Thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to chalk this one up as experience. Having found a javascript function that was causing the abort the problem is now resolved.